# Azure Migrate - Agentless VMWare migration stuck 'In progress'

Tags: azure-migrate

Has anyone come across an issue in Azure Migrate where a test migration takes ~10 minutes but an actual migration was still 'in progress' after 90 minutes? We just had to back out of a customer file server migration because we ran out of time. I ran another test migration straight after we cancelled and this also took 10 minutes to run successfully.

Its an agentless VMware migration, ~4TB of data (but replication is healthy and at 'delta sync' status). Test migration works fine & appliance diagnostics dont show any problems. Upload bandwidth from the source is ~700mb & plenty of CPU & ram overhead on VMware host & appliance VM. The VM was shut down for migration, Veeam backups disabled (there is an incompatibility there because Migrate & Veeam both use change block tracking).

I can't find any logs or other data to indicate what the problem might have been. Does anyone have any ideas?